# Identify bad data in azure data explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a dataset and I need to filter bad/invalid data for my compute. I tried percentile but that will filter genuine value

Eg: 1, 2,8,10,20,25,55,100,100000,98,99,95

Here, 100000 is corrupted/bad, When I call Max () function, I expect 100 instead of 100000.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and a sample output and describe the applicable logic?

Comment: In my above example, If I want to fetch Min, Avg, Max, it will result as 1, 8376, 100000. But I want 1, 46.6, 100 - Here Avg and Max excludes 100000

Comment: Is there a way to get second max value?

Answer (score 0):

[series_outliers()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-outliersfunction)

```
datatable(val:int)[1, 2,8,10,20,25,55,100,100000,98,99,95]
| summarize val = make_list(val)
| extend anomaly_score = series_outliers(val)
| mv-expand val to typeof(int), anomaly_score to typeof(real);
//| where anomaly_score between (-1.5 .. 1.5)
```

| val | anomaly_score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.045592692382452886 |
| 2 | -0.017097259643419842 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 25 | 0 |
| 55 | 0 |
| 100 | 0.0028495432739035469 |
| 100000 | 2846.6965801726751 |
| 98 | 0 |
| 99 | 0 |
| 95 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12O2wrCMAyG732KXG6QHaGwKT6JyOhcxGK7jrY7yR7e7EJEcyCBfP9POhk4W03RJPVR9SG%20FAglVljkWHIJFIL3fG8OrCusa6zF9bCBH42RTr0IWAxnMPJJjVY%207GYxA7QE6juQvTVSr42/WUfMeXKKfGPHoBU5/6HNlNAySBbsdsFCWAey92j/Cv9MvldHrD4dsmyD%20UF8%20gVbCjNRD1FSpALSFHjEb0MDfCP2AAAA)